# Airplanes crashworthiness and ETSC report

Tags: safety

I have recently found this link that shows a report of European Transport Safety Council: https://etsc.eu/increasing-the-survival-rate-in-aircraft-accidents-impact-protection-fire-survivability-and-evacuation/ . This seems to be dated to 1996. What I don't understand is why a lot of recommendations are not yet implemented? Most of them don't look like they would imply a lot of costs or extra training, but they would for sure improve the survivability rate, at least in case of a fire or smoke.

Also I have recently read about the Burnelli airplane wich has a way higher crashworthiness score (but it has some extra air drag which I guess increases the fuel costs), but still I think even a small safety improvement should be above costs or econonics. Why are they not in use today if they provide extra safety and also lower takeoff/landing speeds (when most of the accidents take place)?

Comment: You're asking 2 distinct and different questions here: 1) Why haven't _recommendations_ been implemented? 2) Why are _extra safety measures_ not in use? If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that we work on a one-question per post basis. Your best bet would be to separate these into 2 different questions. You'll probably also want to be more explicit in exactly what you're asking because these seem rather broad questions. Also, "a small safety improvement" is often not "above cost/economics" because the cost is high and the improvement is small.

Comment: Agreed! I will try to split this into two questions. Regarding the improvement vs cost, in the and it will be propagated to the customer, and I think there is not one person which would not pay an extra premium knowing that it adds an extra safety. But anyways, some of the recommentations seems quite cheap, like for example 3 point seatbelts.

Comment: "I think there is not one person which would not pay an extra premium knowing that it adds an extra safety" - I think you're working under an incorrect assumption here. Look at how many people pass up on creature comforts (like a place to put their legs when sitting in a plane seat) in exchange for saving a few dollars on a ticket. If it weren't for consumer's _extreme_ price sensitivity, low-cost carriers wouldn't exist. Also, there can be _huge_ additional maintenance costs for that added "safety" that just doesn't make it economically feasible.

Comment: I'm betting if you search through the [tag:safety] questions, you see all _sorts_ of "Why don't they do `x` to improve safety" questions, 99.9999% of which are answered by "the added cost compared to the added safety isn't viable".